# Why pressing alt+1 for changing view axis works only in edit mode?

Tags: shortcut

I don't have a numpad so I changed view axis to alt + number.

Comment: In my version of Blender nothing happens when using ALT + ordinary 1 key

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Did you change the keymap for it to do something?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Vanilla Blender, Alt + 1 on Windows does nothing for me. By ordinary 1 key I mean NOT numpad key.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady But you did read the title and the question, didn't you? ;) He changed the keymap from _Numpad 1_ to _Alt + 1_ because he has no numpad. Now _Alt + 1_ works like _Numpad 1_, but only in _Edit Mode_, not in _Object Mode_. The question he asks is: why doesn't it work in _Object Mode_, since the keymap can only be changed in general, not separately for both modes, and since _Numpad 1_ works in both, he assumed the changed _Alt + 1_ should do the same.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Hmmmmm.... I'm going to go with "He edited the question within the 5 minutes of posting it" :D That's definitely what happened!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady *lol* definitely! :D

Answer (score 1):

I only have one explanation, most likely <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is bound in some other way so that it cannot be used in *Object Mode*.

But I have to admit I checked for other key bindings of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and changing them to something different (although they didn't seem to do anything when I tried) still didn't help making it work in *Object Mode*.

However, an indication that my suspicion is true: when I changed <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to something completely different which I assumed to have no other function in Blender - in this case I used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or something like that - then it suddenly worked in *Edit Mode* **and** *Object Mode*.

So I guess you just have to find some other shortcut that suits you better and works in both modes.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to just numbers and still it works only in edit mode. WEIRD :D

Comment: @ArtoMikaelMuukka Not weird. Just numbers have assignments in _Object Mode_, so I guess it's the same reason as for Alt+1. I'm afraid you might have to come up with something more odd or complex, as the simple shortcuts are most likely all occupied.